# Installed Windows 7 Ultimate on D Drive and previous Windows 7 Enterprise on C Drive has stopped starting up

Tags: windows-7, windows, multi-boot

Please please help!

I have installed Windows 7 Ultimate on same hard drive on `D Drive` on my laptop and the previous Windows 7 Enterprise which was installed on `C Drive` is not booting up now.

When I turn on my laptop, I see two Windows 7 on the screen, when I select newer one, it starts, but when I select older one which is Enterprise edition, system won't start and I get the DOS black screen with this error message:

> **Windows Boot Manager**
>   
>     Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:
>
> 1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer.
> 2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
> 3. Click "repair your computer."
>
> Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is
>   inaccessible.

I notice that when I run the newer OS installed, the previous OS's drive (Which is D: now instead of C:) has become unusable and when I double click it, it asks me to format the drive.

The data, that I had on my `D Drive (Which is now C Drive for new OS)`, I had copied it to a network path and it is available. It was containing Windows 7 `Users` folder which I copied at that time when installing new windows.

I have copied that `Users` folder again to the new OS's C Drive thinking it would run again, but of no use.

Please please please...if someone can help...It is extremely required for me.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I am unable to open the previous OS's drive in new OS. Does windows 7 formats all drives even if I selected only one drive on which I wanted to install the OS?

Comment: Why do you want us to close your question? Under which close reason?

Comment: Because there is no answer available that I can accept.

Comment: Then we'll just leave this question open. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

You  can try to repair the bootloader using the Windows recovery disk. At least that will bring some clarity to the situation by marking each OS.

After doing this boot into one of the Windows installs and install EasyBCD and check the boot paths properly.

Comment: I have tried running EasyBCD on the new Windows & installed. It is showing two entries with current one and the previous one on D Drive which is correct.

Comment: I usually rely on the Windows Disk to fix my boot problems, YMMV. You can at least run some commands to find out what exactly is going on.